# Combination from a table with specific criteria

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

I have a table with Day as a column header and temperature as the row. The table states the number of times a day had a given minimum temperature. In the table below Mondays had a minimum temperature of 1 degree four times, Tuesday had a minimum temperature of 1 degree 0 times and Wednesday had a minimum temperature of 1 degree 3 times and so on.

```
     **Mon**       **Tue**      **Wed**     
1      4              0            3
2      0              1            0
3      1              4            2
4      2              0            1
5      0              1            3    
6      7              3            2
7      0              0            1
8      2              1            4
```

I want to generate all possible combinations `(a,b,c)` of temperatures and 
days which signify equally spaced values such that `(a-b) = 3` and `(b-c) = 0`.

Monday with a min temperature of 1 degree = 4
Tuesday with a min temperature of 2 degrees = 1
Difference = 3

Tuesday with a min temperature of 2 degrees = 1
Wednesday with a min temperature 4 degrees = 1
Difference = 0

Output value as row label: `(1,2,4)`, `(1,2,7)` and `(6,3,8)`

How should I get similar combinations of equally spaced values across the whole table?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I have understood the requirement clear. But check if this is what you need:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> temperatures = [
    [4,0,3],
    [0,1,0],
    [1,4,2],
    [2,0,1],
    [0,1,3],
    [7,3,2],
    [0,0,1],
    [2,1,4]
]
>>> monday_values,tuesday_values,wednesday_values = zip(*temperatures)
>>> result = []
>>> for i,j,k in product(range(len(monday_values)), range(len(tuesday_values)), range(len(wednesday_values))):
        # remove same day values
        if i==j or j==k or k==i:
            continue
        if (monday_values[i]-tuesday_values[j]==3) and (tuesday_values[j]-wednesday_values[k]==0):
            result.append((i+1,j+1,k+1))


>>> result
[(1, 2, 4), (1, 2, 7), (1, 5, 4), (1, 5, 7), (1, 8, 4), (1, 8, 7), (6, 3, 8)]
```

Comment: Thank You. I can start with this for now. The issue is that I have an excel table with 30 rows and 30 columns to apply the criteria. Categorizing data would be an issue. A more lazy solution to automatically categorize data automatically would be greatly appreciated.